# TSQL Parsing 3rd Element

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a field that contains data like this:

```
1763_250116_0_040
1763_250132_4_030
1763_250132_99999_030
```

I need to get out:

```
0
4
99999
```

How could I accomplish this with TSQL?

Comment: always 4 elements/

Comment: There are hundreds of questions about string splitting already. Please do some research first... The linked answer contains great approaches, but many of them are outdated. I'd have a look at the younger / more active ones...

Answer (score 0):

Substring and some others string manipulations

```
declare @table table (c1 varchar(64))
insert into @table
values
('1763_250116_0_040'),
('1763_250132_4_030'),
('1763_250132_99999_030_000_0000_000')

select
    substring(right(c1, len(c1) - charindex('_',c1,charindex('_',c1,0) + 1)),0,charindex('_',right(c1, len(c1) - charindex('_',c1,charindex('_',c1,0) + 1))))
from @table
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have only 4 or less parts of numbers in the text and you always want the third part, then you should probably use the built-in function [PARSENAME](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/parsename-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017).

```
select PARSENAME (REPLACE(CONVERT(NVARCHAR(100),c1),'_','.') , 2)   
FROM T
GO
```

this solution best fit your sample data, but read the limitation which I mentioned above. For text in this format this should be best probably: `<number>_<number>_<number which we want to get>_<number>`